# JavaScript onClick Reset and or different result

Tags: javascript

I am new at JavaScript and was stuck figuring out this problem today.

I have a button and 2 rectangles, one red one blue. Once I click the button the switch places (more like color), what I am trying to figure out is to make the second click revert back to the original state that these 2 rectangles been. So far it only works one way.

Any response will be appreciated!

```js
function changeColorOfElementID(id, color){

 document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;

}
```

```css
#aRectangle{
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 left:100px;
 top:100px;
 background-color: blue;
 z-index:1;
}
#aRectangle2{
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 left:110px;
 top:110px;
 background-color: red;
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Color Switch</title>
 <script src="js/code.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="changeColorOfElementID('aRectangle', 'red'); changeColorOfElementID('aRectangle2', 'blue'); " >Change Color</button>

<div id="aRectangle"></div>
<div id="aRectangle2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It only works on way because that is what you are telling him to do. You say: when someone click change this to red and the other to blue. So when a user clicks it changes the color but then when he click again he tries to change red to red and blue to blue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function changeColorOfElementID(id){

    if(document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == 'red')
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

    else
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="changeColorOfElementID('aRectangle'); changeColorOfElementID('aRectangle2'); " >Change Color</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, it was close to what was required!


the only difference i did 2 functions one was changeColorOfElementID1 and changeColorOfElementID2 after in the button i associated the"a rectangle" to the first one and "arectangle2" to the second, as well as adjust colour pattern.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this

```
function toggleElementColor(id1,id2){
  var element1 = document.getElementById(id1);
  var element2 = document.getElementById(id2);

  var element1Color = element1.style.backgroundColor;
  var element2Color = element2.style.backgroundColor;

  element1.style.backgroundColor = element2Color;
  element2.style.backgroundColor = element1Color;
}
```

and You like this

```
<button onClick="toggleElementColor('aRectangle','aRectangle2');" >Change Color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone really helped me out!

This was the solution that was derived from all the help received:

```js
function changeColorOfElementID1(id){

    if(document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == 'red')
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

    else
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}

function changeColorOfElementID2(id){

    if(document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == 'blue')
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    else
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
}
```

```css
#aRectangle{
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 left:100px;
 top:100px;
 background-color: blue;
 z-index:1;
}
#aRectangle2{
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 left:110px;
 top:110px;
 background-color: red;
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Color Switch</title>
 <script src="js/code.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="changeColorOfElementID1('aRectangle'); changeColorOfElementID2('aRectangle2'); " >Change Color</button>
<div id="aRectangle"></div>
<div id="aRectangle2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```